# How to retrieve FormData values from Yii 1.1 back-end?

Tags: json, reactjs, yii, redux, form-data

I am building a page in this platform that will require a title and a file. I am using `FormData`. I've already used it like this with another back-end framework where I appended a string and a file to the `FormData`:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("title", this.state.title);
data.append("file", this.state.file[0]);
```

I am using Redux, so this is the action that will communicate with the back-end:

```
export function createDownloadableForm(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { auth: { oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret } } = getState();

    return dispatch({
      [CALL_API]: {
        endpoint: "/api/downloadable-forms",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'xoauthtoken': oauthToken,
          'xoauthtokensecret': oauthTokenSecret,
        },
        body: data,
        types: [CREATE_DOWNLOADABLE_FORMS, CREATE_DOWNLOADABLE_FORMS_SUCCESS, CREATE_DOWNLOADABLE_FORMS_FAILURE]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But now I need to access this information from the back-end. How do I do it since what I send is not a JSON? How do I recover the appended data in `FormData`?

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $request = \Yii::app()->request;
    // ?
}
```

I've done few things to check what was being sent. One,

```
\Yii::log(json_encode($request));
```

will display

> {"jsonAsArray":true,"enableCookieValidation":false,"enableCsrfValidation":false,"csrfTokenName":"YII_CSRF_TOKEN","csrfCookie":null,"behaviors":[]}

Using `getPost` and passing the name of the fields do not work either, it is `null`. `getRaw`, just in case something else would be shown, shows nothing as well. It is like nothing is being sent, but the code for sending `FormData`, the way it is, was used before and works.

Comment: Did you tried to check what is in `$_POST`?

Comment: Yes. It always shows empty. Look my updated question, please.

Comment: You did't showed result of `var_dump($_POST)`. Did you really tried to check what is in `$_POST`?

Comment: It shows `array(0) { }`.

Comment: If I send a simple JSON, as a common form storing string data, `var_dump($_POST)` or `getPost("title")`will also display `NULL`, however using `var_dump($request->getJSON("title"))` this time will display the data being sent. The thing is then how to access `FormData`. I cannot use `getJSON`.